# Simple block factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-element-method

In the two substructures case for the finite element tearing and interconnecting method (FETI) from "Domain Decomposition: Parallel Multilevel Methods for Elliptic Partial Differential Equations" (pp 104, Smith 1996), the finite element stiffness matrix $A$ can be represented by representing the interior indices $I$ and boundary indices $B$ as shown below:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
A_{II}^{(1)} & 0            & A_{IB}^{(1)} \\
0            & A_{II}^{(2)} & A_{IB}^{(2)} \\
A_{BI}^{(1)} & A_{BI}^{(2)}  & A_{BB}^{(1)} + A_{BB}^{(2)} 
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{1}
$$

But "An Introduction to Domain Decomposition Methods: Algorithms, Theory, and Parallel Implementation" (pp 132, Dolean 2015) states "a simple computation shows that we have a block factorization" as below:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 & 0 \\
0 & I & 0 \\
A_{BI}^{(1)}A_{II}^{(1)^{-1}} & A_{BI}^{(2)}A_{II}^{(2)^{-1}} & I
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
A_{II}^{(1)} & 0            & 0 \\
0            & A_{II}^{(2)} & 0 \\
0            & 0 & S^{(1)} + S^{(2)} 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 & A_{II}^{(1)^{-1}}A_{IB}^{(1)} \\ 
0 & I & A_{II}^{(2)^{-1}}A_{IB}^{(2)} \\ 
0 & 0 & I
\end{bmatrix}. \tag{2}
$$

**How can I show that this block factorization (2) follows from (1)? And why would you perform this block factorization in the first place?** Note that ${S^{(i)} = A_{BB}^{(i)} - A_{BI}^{(i)}A_{II}^{(i)^{-1}} A_{IB}^{(i)}}$ and that $I$ is the identity matrix if standing alone.

Edit:

Given (2), it's easy to see that for example, the 3rd row and 1st column element of $A$ follows easily from the corresponding matrix multiplication,
$$
A_{31} = I(A_{BI}^{(1)}A_{II}^{(1)^{-1}}A_{II}^{(1)} + A_{BI}^{(2)}A_{II}^{(2)^{-1}} 0 + I 0) = A_{BI}^{(1)},
$$

but without seeing (2), I wouldn't necessarily make this observation immediately. *So if you weren't given (2), how would you approach the factorization?*

Comment: There are more matrix factorization then just $LU$, from what I know $QR$ or $SVD$ are quite common. What exactly is your question? As you write, it is easy to compute and check that the factorization is ok. If you want to know why would anyone come up with such strangely looking factorization, it actually just corresponds to the (block) Gauss elimination of the $II$ block(s).

Comment: I'll update the question, because I see how it could be unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could obtain a factorization like this by using "block-row" operations. Begin with
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
A_{II}^{(1)} & 0            & A_{IB}^{(1)} \\
0            & A_{II}^{(2)} & A_{IB}^{(2)} \\
A_{BI}^{(1)} & A_{BI}^{(2)}  & A_{BB}^{(1)} + A_{BB}^{(2)} 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
If we multiply the first row by $A_{BI}^{(1)}[A_{II}^{(1)}]^{-1}$ (from the left), then the resulting first entry will match the $3,1$ block entry. Thus, the block-row operation $R_3 = R_3 - A_{BI}^{(1)}[A_{II}^{(1)}]^{-1}R_1$ will "zero out" the $3,1$ entry. Writing this out in matrix form, we have
$$
\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 & 0\\
0 & I & 0\\
-A_{BI}^{(1)}[A_{II}^{(1)}]^{-1} & 0 & I
\end{bmatrix}}^{E_1}
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{II}^{(1)} & 0            & A_{IB}^{(1)} \\
0            & A_{II}^{(2)} & A_{IB}^{(2)} \\
A_{BI}^{(1)} & A_{BI}^{(2)}  & A_{BB}^{(1)} + A_{BB}^{(2)} 
\end{bmatrix} = \\
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{II}^{(1)} & 0            & A_{IB}^{(1)} \\
0            & A_{II}^{(2)} & A_{IB}^{(2)} \\
0 & A_{BI}^{(2)}  & A_{BB}^{(1)} + A_{BB}^{(2)} - A_{BI}^{(1)}[A_{II}^{(1)}]^{-1}A_{IB}^{(1)}
\end{bmatrix} = \\
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{II}^{(1)} & 0            & A_{IB}^{(1)} \\
0            & A_{II}^{(2)} & A_{IB}^{(2)} \\
0 & A_{BI}^{(2)}  & S^{(1)} + A_{BB}^{(2)}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
You can think of the $E_1$ as being analogous to an [elementary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix). Notably, the inverse of the "block elementary matrix" $E_1$ will be the block elementary matrix of the inverse operation, namely the matrix corresponding to $R_3 = R_3 - A_{BI}^{(1)}[A_{II}^{(1)}]^{-1}R_1$.

From there, you can find a block elementary matrix $E_2$ such that
$$
E_2 \begin{bmatrix}
A_{II}^{(1)} & 0            & A_{IB}^{(1)} \\
0            & A_{II}^{(2)} & A_{IB}^{(2)} \\
0 & A_{BI}^{(2)}  & S^{(1)} + A_{BB}^{(2)}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{II}^{(1)} & 0            & A_{IB}^{(1)} \\
0            & A_{II}^{(2)} & A_{IB}^{(2)} \\
0 & 0  & S^{(1)} + S^{(2)}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
From there, you could proceed by using block elementary matrices corresponding to row-multiplications in order to get $I$'s on the diagonal, but the punchline is that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{II}^{(1)} & 0            & 0 \\
0            & A_{II}^{(2)} & 0 \\
0 & 0  & S^{(1)} + S^{(2)}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{II}^{(1)} & 0            & A_{IB}^{(1)} \\
0            & A_{II}^{(2)} & A_{IB}^{(2)} \\
0 & 0  & S^{(1)} + S^{(2)}
\end{bmatrix} = \\
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 & A_{II}^{(1)^{-1}}A_{IB}^{(1)} \\ 
0 & I & A_{II}^{(2)^{-1}}A_{IB}^{(2)} \\ 
0 & 0 & I
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Putting all that together, we have found that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{II}^{(1)} & 0            & 0 \\
0            & A_{II}^{(2)} & 0 \\
0 & 0  & S^{(1)} + S^{(2)}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}E_2E_1 A = \begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 & A_{II}^{(1)^{-1}}A_{IB}^{(1)} \\ 
0 & I & A_{II}^{(2)^{-1}}A_{IB}^{(2)} \\ 
0 & 0 & I
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Solving for $A$ yields
$$
A = [E_1^{-1}E_2^{-1}]\begin{bmatrix}
A_{II}^{(1)} & 0            & 0 \\
0            & A_{II}^{(2)} & 0 \\
0 & 0  & S^{(1)} + S^{(2)}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 & A_{II}^{(1)^{-1}}A_{IB}^{(1)} \\ 
0 & I & A_{II}^{(2)^{-1}}A_{IB}^{(2)} \\ 
0 & 0 & I
\end{bmatrix},
$$
which is the block-factorization from (2).

As for why this kind of factorization would be useful, I'm guessing the intent is to speed up the computation of $A^{-1}$. Note that when $A = PQR$, we have $A^{-1} = R^{-1}Q^{-1}P^{-1}$. The individual inverses $P^{-1}, Q^{-1}, R^{-1}$ are relatively quick to compute due to the nice structure that each matrix has.